# How do I return the original http method when using app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**Background**

I want to log the original http method (post / get / head) that was used when an error was encountered.

I have a Web application in asp.net Core v3.0 and I make use of the `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/Status/{0}");` middleware to take users to an error view, which in turns, invokes the status action on my errorcontroller.

*ErrorController.cs extract*

```cs
[Route("[controller]/[action]/{statusCode}")]
public IActionResult Status(int? statusCode)
{
    return ErrorViewModel(statusCode: statusCode);
}

[NonAction]
private IActionResult ErrorViewModel(int? statusCode = null)
{
    var exception = HttpContext.Features
                        .Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
    var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();
    string requestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
    string userAgent = HttpContext.Request?.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
    string originalMethod = ""; //WHERE CAN THIS BE DERIVED FROM?
    var errorMessage = exception?.Error?.Message;
    bool hasMessage = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorMessage);

    ErrorViewModel vm = new ErrorViewModel
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage,
        StatusCode = statusCode,
        UserAgent = userAgent,
        RequestId = requestId,
        OriginalMethod = originalMethod,
        OriginalPath = feature?.OriginalPath,
        OriginalQueryString = feature?.OriginalQueryString
    };

    string logMessage = vm.GetLogMessage();
    bool hasBeenLogged = false;
    if (WebsiteConfig.WebsiteLogging.LogWhenGeneralError || hasMessage)
    {
        _logger.LogError(logMessage);
        hasBeenLogged = true;
    }

    //if we don't want to be sent an email and don't log it as an error above, let's still log it as a piece of information for audit
    if (!hasBeenLogged)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(logMessage);
        hasBeenLogged = true;
    }

    return View("Error", vm);
}
```

*ErrorViewModel.cs*

```cs
public class ErrorViewModel
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public int? StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
    public string UserAgent { get; set; }
    public string OriginalPath { get; set; }
    public string OriginalQueryString { get; set; }
    public string OriginalMethod { get; set; }

    public string FullOriginalPath => $"{OriginalPath}{OriginalQueryString}";
    public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);
    public bool ShowGeneralError => StatusCode != 404 && StatusCode != 403 && StatusCode != 401;

    public string GetLogMessage()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine($"Request Id: {RequestId}");
        sb.AppendLine($"Status code: {StatusCode}");
        sb.AppendLine($"User agent: {UserAgent}");
        sb.AppendLine($"Original Method: {OriginalMethod}");
        sb.AppendLine($"Original FullPath: {FullOriginalPath}");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ErrorMessage))
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"Error Message: {ErrorMessage}");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Question**

As you can see from above I can locate the original path and querystring using the Feature `IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature`. It's a shame there isn't an original method with this:

```cs
var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();
...
OriginalPath = feature?.OriginalPath,
OriginalQueryString = feature?.OriginalQueryString
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get hold of the original method (post / get / head / etc)? I can see there's a HttpContext.Features.Method property but this is always set to "get" even if I post to an unknown action as a test.

[image: Watch on HttpContext.Features]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the original Exception that was thrown.
Using the the `TargetSite` property we can get the `MethodBase` that threw the exception, on it there is the property `Name` which tells you the name, and the property `ReflectedType` with the property `Name` which tells you the name of the class of the exception.

So like this:

```cs
var exception = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

var method = exception?.Error?.Name;
var class = exception?.Error?.ReflectedType.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @MindSwipe but it was the http method I was asking in my question (post / get / head / etc) rather than the calling method in code. I explicitly asked this in the question section of my question. I've expanded this on the opening sentence too as I can see how you thought I was asking what you answered. Don't suppose you know how to get the original http method?

Comment: Ah ok, my bad. I get distracted easily. Well getting the HTTP request method may be a little harder, but I have an explanation as to why the HttpContext.Method always says "GET", because you are redirecting to the Error page, so the browser is executing a GET on the /Error endpoint. I'll be researching it further, but I'm not at a computer right now but I'll try and follow up. If I don't just ping me with an @MindSwipe comment here

Comment: That's what I figured on why I was seeing "GET" as the context method. It'd be really useful to be able to log this accurately rather than having to go trawling through IIS logs! Any ideas?

Comment: Ping @MindSwipe, I still haven't been able to resolve this. Did you have any luck with your research?